# Repository method for finding node connected to arbitrary number of other nodes

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

In spring-data-neo4j, I can use the following repository method to find a `Foo` node connected to two given `Bar` nodes:

```
interface FooRepo extends GraphRepository<FooNode> { 
    @Query ("START a=node({0}), z=node({1}) " +  
            "MATCH (a)-[:REL]->(x:foo)<-[:REL]-(z) RETURN x")  
    Foo getFooBetween(Bar a, Bar b); 
 }
```

I want to write a similar repository method to find a `Foo` that's connected to an arbitrary number of `Bar`s :

```
     @Query // ?? 
    Foo getFooBetween(Bar... bars);
```

How might I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this.

```
@Query("MATCH (bar:Bar)-[r:REL]->(foo:Foo)
        WHERE ID(bar) IN {0}
        WITH foo, COLLECT(bar) AS rels
        WHERE length(rels) = length({0})
        RETURN foo
Foo getFooBetween(List<Long> barIds)
```

It matches all the Bars by the IDs that you have passed in and then finds all the Foos that each of those Bar's is related to. It them test to see if there are the expected number of relationships. This will not work if you have multiple relationships of the same type between a given Foo and Bar.

To cater for that you can add a `DISTINCT` modifier in the `COLLECT` aggregation:

```
WITH foo, COLLECT(DISTINCT bar) AS rels
```